# How to fit selected features to page using openlayers2.13?

Tags: openlayers-2

I want to select feature and then fit feature to page bound.

I use this code:

```
selected.geometry.resize(2, origin);
```

my code, double the selected, but i want fit selected to page bound. I do not know how to calculate scale and put in place 2 in the above code.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
function fitToScale(){

    // get min , max bound of selected features;

    minBoundX=vectors.selectedFeatures[0].geometry.getBounds().left;
    minBoundY=vectors.selectedFeatures[0].geometry.getBounds().top;
    maxBoundX=vectors.selectedFeatures[0].geometry.getBounds().right;
    maxBoundY=vectors.selectedFeatures[0].geometry.getBounds().bottom;
    for(i=0 ; i &lt; vectors.selectedFeatures.length ; i++){
        gBound = vectors.selectedFeatures[i].geometry.getBounds();
        if(minBoundX>gBound.left){
            minBoundX=gBound.left;
        }
        if(minBoundY>gBound.bottom){
            minBoundY=gBound.bottom;
        }
        if(maxBoundX&lt;gBound.right){
            maxBoundX=gBound.right;
        }
        if(maxBoundY&lt;gBound.top){
            maxBoundY=gBound.top;
        }
    }

    // get page bound , ratio of page bound and features bound
    var mBound = map.getExtent();
    var dx1=maxBoundX-minBoundX;
    var dy1=maxBoundY-minBoundY;
    var dx2=mBound.right-mBound.left;
    var dy2=mBound.top-mBound.bottom;
    var area1=dx2/dx1;
    var area2=dy2/dy1;
    var min;

    if(area1&lt;area2){
        min=area1;
    } else{
        min=area2;
    }
    console.log(min);

    // claculate center of features and add center point to features
    var x=(maxBoundX+minBoundX)/2;
    var y=(maxBoundY+minBoundY)/2;
    origin = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(x,y);
    // create new line with center point
    for(i=0;i&lt;vectors.selectedFeatures.length;i++ ){
        selected = vectors.selectedFeatures[i];
        pLine=[];
        for(j=0;j&lt;selected.geometry.getVertices().length;j++ ){
            pLine.push(selected.geometry.getVertices()[j]);
        }
        pLine.push(origin);
        newLine=new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(pLine));
        vectors.addFeatures(newLine);
        // resize and fit selected features to page bound 
        newLine.geometry.resize(min, origin);
        vectors.removeFeatures(newLine);
        vectors.redraw();
    }

}
```

I hope it can help you.